# Syncronize Scrolling with NgRx

Tags: javascript, typescript, synchronization, ngrx, ngrx-store

I want to sync two scrollable Lists(in different Components, but same view) using NgRx. How would I implement this?

I would really appreciate the help!

I'm familiar with the concept of NgRx, but can't really apply it to a new use case.

I have a model, which should store the scroll position and the displayedElements of a Tree List:

`export interface ListStateModel{ scrollY: number displayedElemList: any[] }`

I have a Action, that (should) send a Object with the two attributes.

`export const getScrollAction = createAction( 'scrolled', props<{ data: ListStateModel }>() );`

I tried creating the reducer (which maybe works):

```
export const initialState: Readonly<ListStateModel> = {displayedElemList: [], scrollY: 0};

export const scollReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(getScrollAction, (_state) =>{
    return _state
    }

  )
)
```

But where i'm really struggeling is the selector and the implementation in the Components

Comment: What have you tried so far, besides creating the reducer?

Comment: I followed the instructions of ngrx tutorial, but only started learning about it two days ago. I also tried multiple other blogs and examples, but i can't seem to implement it on my own. I've created the actions, reducer and selector with various implementations.